# Can't upload screenshots for my application in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I try to change the screenshots of my application due to an update but apple gives me error:

> A network timeout error occurred. Please try again later.

Any help?

Comment: I get the same network timeout problem too :(
How did you solve it?

Comment: This problem has reappeared in Safari Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2) just now. I used Chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with iTunes Connect and not a programming issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please switch the browser to other then mozilla ... i got the same error on mozilla ... i tried google chrome and setup new app and its good and done ... mozilla have some clashes in the new updates. .

Problem Solved .. !!

Comment: Currently I can't with Safari, but with Chrome it was alright.

Answer (score 8):

While switching to a different browser is a work around, it's not a fix.  Here is the fix:

Open Safari `Preferences...`

Click the `Privacy` Tab

Next to #### websites stored cookies.... hit `Details...`

In the search box type `Apple`.

Click `apple.com` in the list and hit `Remove`.

Bob will then be your uncle.

Comment: When this error happened to me on 8 Dec 2013, this solution worked for me.. thanks! Switching browsers (as suggested by others) didn't help. At least, both chrome and safari showed me that BS error message.

Comment: Yeah I was getting it yesterday 7 Dec 2013 and came here to find a checkmarked non-answer. Figured it had to be something cached. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Great tip! I think my network error, but not. I love to do all task on Safari then other browser

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a browser issue. I upgraded to Firefox 7 yesterday and that is when I stopped being able to upload screenshots. I switched to Safari and had no issue uploading the images.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a Firefox 7 issue: I've been struggling with this since yesterday. Switching to Safari did the trick.