# iTunes Connect Error when add new IOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to add new iOS App to `iTunes Connect`.

I have all `AppID` , `Development & Distribution Provision certificates` for my iOS App.

I have already fill all requirements metadata , screenshots , descriptions , etc... in iTunesConnect.

However when i save the following error is occurring.

I tried with many browsers and all are the same result.

My App is `Photo/Video` App with `Universal`.

How can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: Hey I am not sure you need to contact apple but alot of account are having same issues and i got any other question submitted right know on stackoverflow and one of my friend having issue from 2 3 days . I think its is current issue with there server. how ever if some one submitted a new app recently successfully can confirm it.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.So i have to wait.

Comment: no contact apple there support is good don't waist your time and also might be you get better reason then I gave you. But i would have contact them

Comment: yes i have contacted to apple support about my problem.

Comment: good luck boos, this is life of coder

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with iTunes Connect and not a programming issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible that it's the same problem that I answered over here:

[Can't upload screenshots for my application in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096496/cant-upload-screenshots-for-my-application-in-itunes-connect/20436731#20436731)

It's likely just a safari cache issue:

Open Safari `Preferences...`

Click the `Privacy` Tab

Next to #### websites stored cookies.... hit `Details...`

In the search box type `Apple`.

Click `apple.com` in the list and hit `Remove`.

Bob will then be your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried Application Loader program rather than uploading through iTunes Connect. If it's still not working try after sometime. i saw in some discussions that it will be ok after sometime.

Comment: I don't know how to create new package from new file. Is there any examples?

Comment: See this link. https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf