# I can't create a new version for any of my apps?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I can't create a new version for any of my apps in Itunes Connect:

**The following error(s) occurred:**

> There was an error saving changes. Please try again later or contact
>   iTunes Connect Support at itunesconnect@apple.com.

Following is the screenshot that I received the error:

[image]

Anybody tried to create a new version today?

Comment: I face the same issue with @Gaurav. I updated the question and added more comments. Please do not downvote.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error when pressing the "Release this version" button on a newly approved app.

Comment: Same problem here can't create new version for an App nor update screenshots for another one created yesterday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been experiencing this exact same issue since 11am (CET) from multiple Developer accounts. Tried in multiple browsers but it seems like a server side issue @Apple. So you're not the only one :)

For a conclusive answer on this it's best to contact iTunes or App Store support.

Comment: +1 for me - have tried multiple apps, browsers and developer accounts.  Definitely seems like an Apple problem.

Comment: You're welcome Guarav Verma. By the way, I'm able to create new app versions again so it seems Apple has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add the version from Safari ? If so, it could be the cause of your issue : [iTunes Connect Error when add new IOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22523311/2791407)

Anyway, try again after a few minutes, there's a lot of questions about that on SO.